# Does root overrides read only permission(even to root) set to directory in unix?

Tags: linux, unix

I have created directory and set read only permission for root using chmod.

> chmod -R 400 some_dir/

but when I try to create any file inside it using touch, I was expecting error message something like

> touch some_dir/hello.txt

"touch: cannot touch `some_dir/hello.txt': Permission denied"

but it creates file "hello.txt" inside it happily, but directory permission if I check it still shows readonly for root. Please explain what I'm missing here, since I was expecting error message which would be displayed if any other user(apart from root) try to create file in that directory?

PS: I'm running as root user.

Comment: This question is off-topic here on Stack Overflow, but yes, being root overrides some permissions. For example, you are allowed to read another user's file that has permission rw------- or even ---------.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is - **Yes**, Root user can create files in a directory that is marked as Read Only. You may argue - why? But that's the whole point of root account. It's a special user and it can do things that others can't.

If you want to prevent the file from *accidental* modifications, you can set the `i` attribute of the file on with `chattr +i` command. This will make the file unchangeable. However, note that it will only prevent accidental modifications. Root users can still just unset the attribute first and then modify the file.

Comment: So why root can't execute a file without exec mode? It is inconsistent..

Comment: It helps to remember that Unix is 50 years old and invented by a handful of smart kids; some of the oldest design decisions make a lot less sense compared to the newer bits.